# How to get directory and filename with their subfolders

Tags: c#

I have an application in wpf where I call a FolderBrowserDialog. My desired out put is to have two separate strings. One string should have the base directory. The other should contain the file with its subfolder. For example, this is the complete folder path: *c:\Documents\TestDirectory\Subfolder\test.txt*

One string should hold the directory *C:\Documents\TestDirectory*

The second should have the following Subfolder\test.txt

I am able to get the working directory just fine. The problem I am having is that I am not getting the subfolder directory.

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
   DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

   if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {

       DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);
       DirectoryInfo[] directories = directory.GetDirectories();

       foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in directories)
       {

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: If you want subfolders, and their subfolders and so on, then check if there is a flag you can pass to get them all recursively. If there is no flag available, then you need to make recursive calls yourself until you have reached the leafs. Search for `c# iterate directory recursively` online and you will find plenty examples.

Comment: Have you tried: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\path\goes\here", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: c:\Documents\TestDirectory\Subfolder\test.txt I get no directories

Comment: Take out the  test.txt. You are absoluting to a file not a directory with subdirectories

Comment: what I want to get is the file with its subfolder(s) but in the FolderBrowserDialog when I choose the subfolder I dont get anything back.

Comment: thank you. With a little bit of tweaking and research on my end I managed to get my desired result. You earn the upvote. For those who down voted me, why do I always get downvoted? I explained my issue as well as I could and have been very responsive with the people writing on my question!